# Git revert with multiple Merges

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-flow

We have a repo with submodules, usually when creating a pull request we do it to develop but in one of our submodules we don't use develop, instead we use develop-build the problem is that develop-build was ahead of develop by 5 commits, some of them are merges, and our team mate created a feature/branch from develop-build but instead of creating the pull request to develop-build he did it to develop, how can I revert all the merges and commits that were done in develop?
I wouldn't like to make a reset hard since I want to keep history of this issue, but if there's no other way then I'll just reset hard.

Answer (score 1):

> I wouldn't like to make a reset hard since I want to keep history of this issue

Why not create a branch to the current develop state, which will reference that history.

```
git checkout -b newBranch
git push -u origin newBranch
```

And *then* reset hard `develop` (communicating the reset to the team, for them to fetch and reset their own `develop` branch to the new resetted `origin/develop`).

Finally, the new branch can be use to make a PR.